# SharePoint server 2013 Event 6398

Tags: sharepoint-server, error

First string:

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAppStateQueryJobDefinition (ID
>   305dbe88-7fa8-4991-a326-a2a22d372866) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.
>
> Sorry, we can't seem to connect to the SharePoint Store. Try again in
>   a bit.

Second string:

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.LMTRepopulationJob (ID
>   877ab595-f451-46bf-a7b2-d8a6c498bd2e) threw an exception. More
>   information is included below.
>
> Unexpected exception in FeedCacheService.IsRepopulationNeeded:
>   Connection to the server terminated,check if the cache host(s) is
>   running .

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First string:**

This error happens because of a default timer job “App State Update” it Retrieves and applies updated information on apps from the SharePoint Store. It includes the availability of updates and information about disabled apps.

Since you have no plan to develop App Updates for the SharePoint Farm, Just disable this Timer Job.

Navigate to SharePoint 2013 Central Administration > Monitoring > Review Job Definition
Find App State Update timer job. Click on it.
Click on Disable

**Second srting:**

Perhaps this means that your Distributed cache Service is not running.  You need to enable it via Central Administration.

[SharePoint 2013 – DCS keeps crashing – distributedcacheservice.exe System.UriFormatException](http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/2012/11/25/distributedcacheserviceexe-systemuriformatexception/)

Answer (score 0):

If **the second error** appears once or twice a day, there is a better solution to change the settings for the job in SharePoint itself.

> To reduce or even completely get rid of this error event, you can address it directly in SharePoint Central Administration. To manage it, take the following steps:
>
> 1. Startup **SharePoint Central Administration**
> 2. Click the **Monitoring link** on the left hand navigation bar
> 3. Click on **Review job definitions** under the **Timer Jobs** heading
> 4. In the Job Definitions screen click the Job History link that shows in the left hand navigation bar
> 5. In the **Job History** screen look at the rightmost **View** option
> 6. Change the **View** option from **All** to **Failed Jobs**
> 7. Locate the failure by time and message based on what you saw in your Windows Event logs (it should say something about **Feed Cache Repopulation Job**)
> 8. Click on the failed job to view and edit its properties
>
> Now that you are editing the properties of the job, you’ll need to decide how
> to edit it to fix it.
>
> Personally, I saw in the job properties that it was scheduled to run every 5 minutes. The event error would only appear once or twice a day. From this error behavior I’m assuming there is some kind of randomly happening lock or timeout. Further, I don’t see why this job would have to run every five minutes… is this super-frequent repopulation really necessary?
>
> Anyway, since the errors seem to be related to the frequency of the run, I changed the service to run once an hour with a generous starting time. So far this has done the trick quite nicely and I haven’t seen any further errors in the log files.

Source: https://jwcooney.com/2017/08/24/sharepoint-error-event-6398-part-2-of-dealing-with-this-error/

Comment: This is just pushing dirt under the rug. You just decrease the frequency of the error.

Comment: @SlavenSemper, I'm agree with you. It doesn't completely solve the problem. But can you share a better solution?

Comment: I am currently monitoring the issue ie. waiting for the error to reappear. I have turned on logging on Distributed Cache service, so we'll see how that goes.